# Duplicate symbol WASM compilation error when using header/hpp for contract

Tags: smart-contract, wasm, compilation

I'm looking to use a hpp file as an interface for multiple contracts. I've created a test contract and receiving a WASM compilation error. I based the test contract on the format used by eosio.token.[cpp](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/master/contracts/eosio.token/src/eosio.token.cpp)/[hpp](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/master/contracts/eosio.token/include/eosio.token/eosio.token.hpp).

> /usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.6.1/bin/wasm-ld: error: duplicate symbol: testcts::test::testact(eosio::name)
>
> defined in /tmp/test.cpp.o
>
> defined in /tmp/test.cpp.o

**test.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>

using namespace eosio;

namespace testcts {
    class [[eosio::contract("testct")]] test : public contract {
        public:
            test(name receiver, name code, datastream<const char*> ds) : contract(receiver, code, ds) { }

            ACTION testact( name user );
    };
}
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.hpp"

namespace testcts {
    void test::testact( name user ) {
        require_auth( user );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the error disappears when I use the `-o` flag to explicitly specify output file:

```
eosio-cpp -o test.wasm test.cpp
```